# Strict aliasing rules for allocated objects

Tags: c, types, c99

> C99 6.5/6 The effective type of an object for an access to its stored
>   value is the declared type of the object, if any. 75)
>
> If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an
>   lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of
>   the lvalue becomes the effective type of the object for that access
>   and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value.
>
> If a value is copied into an object having no declared type using
>   memcpy or memmove, or is copied as an array of character type, then
>   the effective type of the modified object for that access and for
>   subsequent accesses that do not modify the value is the effective type
>   of the object from which the value is copied, if it has one. For all
>   other accesses to an object having no declared type, the effective
>   type of the object is simply the type of the lvalue used for the
>   access.
>
> 75) Allocated objects have no declared type.

As stated in C99, the effective type of static objects is their declared type.

How do allocated objects get their effective types?

For example:

```
int *p = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
```

Why don't they have a declared type to begin with?

Comment: The second paragraph, the one beginning "If a value is stored into an object having no declared type" answers your question precisely.

Answer (score 1):

An allocated object hasn't got any declared type, so its effective type is the type of the lvalue used for the access. With this single statement, `p` hasn't effective type:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int *p = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
```

Otherwise, it will have one with the next access:

```
/* Effective type of p: unsigned int */
*(unsigned int *)p = 20U;
```

Comment: At the end it says, `and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value` Is it not allowed to modify the value or something once we have an effective type?

Comment: If a subsequent access modifies the stored value, does the effective type become undeclared again?

Comment: @VilhelmGray: If a subsequent access modifies the stored value, the effective type will become whatever would be implied by that access, if anything.  If the access would not establish a new declared type, the object will go back to having no effective type (and thus be usable as any type).  The Standard is a mess, however, since writing with a character-pointer type effectively erases the Effective Type unless a compiler perceives that an array of characters is being copied (in which case the effective type gets copied).  Nothing in the Standard, however, makes clear what that means.