# Can std::malloc create an object? Is placement new always required?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Does this code have undefined behavior in C++?

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    int *ip = static_cast<int *>(std::malloc(sizeof *ip));
    *ip = 42; //is this accessing an object that has not started its lifetime?
    free(ip);
}
```

Notes:
[`std::malloc` has the semantics that it has in C](http://eel.is/c++draft/c.malloc#2). In C `std::malloc` creates valid `int`s, so it should be valid?

> The lifetime of an object or reference is a runtime property of the
>   object or reference. An object is said to have non-vacuous
>   initialization if it is of a class or aggregate type and it or one of
>   its subobjects is initialized by a constructor other than a trivial
>   default constructor. [ Note: Initialization by a trivial copy/move
>   constructor is non-vacuous initialization. — end note  ] The lifetime
>   of an object of type T begins when:
>
> (1.1)
>       storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and
>      (1.2)
>       if the object has non-vacuous initialization, its initialization is complete,
>
> except that if the object is a union member or subobject thereof ...

[source](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life)

I'm fairly sure this quote answers my question but I don't understand it well enough to tell if it is saying yes or no.

Comment: Related [“constructing” a trivially-copyable object with memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30114397/1708801)

Comment: That quote is not relevant, and this has been discussed what feels like 1 million times. Hang on, I'll look for a dupe.

Comment: Maybe duplicate [At what point does memory allocated by malloc get a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36024325/1708801)

Comment: Don't use `malloc`/`free` in C++. Use `new`/`delete`. Or better yet; don't. Use RAII, automatic objects, containers and smart pointers and avoid manual memory management.

Comment: I assume there's a good reason the standard committee changed "non-trivial initialization" to "non-vacuous initialization", but I sure don't like the new term.  I thought that "vacuous" on that link might have come from some computer-based language translation or something, but I see it's in C++17.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: It's getting around the fact that a "trivial" copy or move constructor does a bitwise image of a valid object.  "vacuous" in contrast means *nothing* is done.

Answer (score -2):

Your object has type `int`, which doesn't require non-trivial initialization, so both bullet points are satisfied just by calling `std::malloc`.

If the object requires a non-trivial constructor call, then `new` is the  way to satisfy (1.2) and if you want to use an allocator other than `operator new()` then placement new is the right approach.