# How to treat a pointer returned by malloc as a multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, malloc

Is there a way to tell the compiler that I've allocated a memory of size N * M and I wanna treat this pointer as N * M array? In other words, is there a way to write something like this?:

```
int arr[N][M] = (int[N][M])malloc(N * M * sizeof(int));
arr[x][y] = 123;
```

I know that the compiler doesn't know the dimensions of the array, all it knows is that that's a pointer. so my question is: can I somehow tell the compiler that this pointer returned by malloc is an array pointer and it's dimensions are N * M? I can use an array to pointers, pointer to arrays or pointer to pointers, but in all cases I'll have to lookup 2 addresses. I want to have a contiguous memory on the heap and treat it as a multidimensional array. just like how I would write:

```
int arr[N][M];
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Are N and M constexpr or #defines ?  Did you try (int[][M])malloc...

Comment: The way to do this is with `std::vector`.  If you need more then one dimension, then you put the vector into a class that fakes that the vector has multiple dimensions. Or, you could just get a library that does this already.

Comment: In C I can write `int (*a)[10]=malloc(100);`.

Comment: This smells like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Can you first explain why you are need this? I'm pretty sure there is another way to tackle you `X` problem.

Comment: `int arr[N][M]` is not a pointer, it is an array.

Comment: @jeffreysupportsMonica I mean by N and M any constant numbers. How should the lhs look like? I tried auto arr = (int[][3])malloc(2 * 3 * sizeof(int)); and it didn't work.

Comment: @NathanOliver Can you provide an example please? I suppose what you're saying is that there is no way to treat a pointer as a multidimensional array. But there is a workaround.

Comment: @Marc Glisse Unfortunately it doesn't work in C++.

Comment: @Marek R I'm sorry if my problem wasn't obvious. But I think I've addressed my problem. I don't wanna access more than one pointer. I want the compiler to use only one pointer to access my elements since some times I don't need to have an array to pointers and my problem can be solved using multidimensional array (I think it's even better since it'll be more efficient). Usually array size is quite big that I can't put it in the stack. But because I don't know how to allocate multidimensional arrays on the heap, I tend to declare an array to pointers.

Comment: @Eljay Yes I know. I want to treat a pointer as an array. In other words I wanna write ptr[x][y] and let the compiler figure out that I mean *(ptr + x * N + M).

Comment: It's technically undefined behaviour to access malloc'd space in C++ ; you should use `new` or higher level containers

Comment: M.M: can you provide a citation?

Comment: @JeffreysupportsMonica https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873520/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024325/

Comment: @StackExchange123 I've added an answer that has a very abbreviated but working concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a C++ program you should use the operator new.

As for malloc then in C++ M shall be a constant expression if you want to allocate a two-dimensional array.

You can write for example

```
int ( *arr )[M] = ( int ( * )[M] )malloc( N * M * sizeof(int) );
```

or

```
int ( *arr )[M] = ( int ( * )[M] )malloc( sizeof( int[N][M] ) );
```

If to use the operator new then the allocation can look like

```
int ( *arr )[M] = new int[N][M];
```

If M is not a compile-time constant then you can use the standard container `std::vector` as it is shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    size_t n = 10, m = 10;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v( n, { m } );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `malloc` like this is UB.  A 2d vector is also terrible.

Comment: @NathanOliver Like what?

Comment: Like how you are using it.  [`malloc` is not one of the ways to create an object](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.object#1.sentence-2) so you don't have an array meaning an use of it is UB.  You'd have to placement new on top of it but array placement new is "broken" and can't be portably used.

Comment: @NathanOliver Do you want to say that all C programs that use malloc have undefined behavior?

Comment: No, Were talking C++ on a C++ question.  If this was a C question you wouldn't be casting and you wouldn't be suggesting `std::vector` or `new`.

Comment: @NathanOliver It does not matter according to the malloc. The reference is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a "matrix" class like

```
template <typename T>
class matrix
{
    size_t len;
    size_t width;
    std::vector<T> data;
public:
    matrix(size_t len, size_t width) : len(len), width(width), data(len*width) {}
    T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) { return data[width * row + col]; }
    const T& operator()(size_t row, size_t col) const { return data[width * row + col]; }
    size_t size() const { return len * width; }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    matrix<int> m(5, 7);
    m(3, 3) = 42;
    std::cout << m(3, 3);
}
```

This keeps all of the data in a single contiguous buffer, and doesn't have any undefined behavior unlike all the other examples that use `malloc`.  It's also RAII, and you don't have to write any copy or move constructors since all of the members "do the right thing" with the compiler provided defaults.  You can make this class more complicated, provide a proxy object so you can overload `operator[]` and be able to do `m[][]`, but at it's base this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you what to avoid use of stack and you need large single block of data to keep two dimensional array of constant size (know at compile time) the this is the best cleanest way to do it:

```
std::vector<std::array<int, M>> arr(N);
arr[x][y] = 3;
```

Now if you need `M` is a value known at run-time, it would be best to use [boost::multi_array](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html)

I do not see a reason to use `malloc`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do exactly what you want with a helper function.  This let's you specify the array size at runtime, and it uses malloc as requested (although typically you should be using `new`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

template <class T>
T** Get2DMalloc(size_t m, size_t n) {
    T** ret = (T**)malloc(sizeof(T*) * m);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        ret[i] = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * n);
    }

    return ret;
}

template <class T>
void Free2D(T** arr, size_t m, size_t n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }

    free(arr);
}

int main() {
    int m = 3;
    int n = 3;

    int** a = Get2DMalloc<int>(3, 3);


    for (int x = 0; x < m; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < n; ++y) {
            a[x][y] = x * m + y;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m * n; ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i / m][i % n] << std::endl;
    }

    Free2D<int>(a, m, n);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `malloc` like this is undefined behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver  Not it isn't, that's absurd. All memory is allocated and freed correctly. Also it directly answers the poster's question. You should know better than to comment like that-- you could harm a new programmer's understanding.

Comment: It's not obsured at all.  In C++, `malloc` **does not create an object**.  If you don't have an object, then any use of that variable besides creating an object in that memory is UB.  This is how C++ works.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024325/at-what-point-does-memory-allocated-by-malloc-get-a-type) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873520/reinterpret-cast-creating-a-trivially-default-constructible-object) for standard citations.